# How to say "Exactly" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-choice

This isn't just a simple translation question--I've already run "exactly" through Google translate, but it didn't give me quite the usage I'm looking for.

Hypothetically, let'ts say I have a friend who posts on Facebook that he got engaged every year on April Fool's Day.

In our (theoretical) scenario, if I wanted to say "It's like you got married to her exactly a year ago!", I would say something like "好像你一年前已經訂婚了" However, in my vocabulary, the "一年前" denotes "roughly one year ago", instead of "Exactly one year to the day ago."

How would I best communicate that he (potentially) pulled the same prank one year ago to the day?

Comment: users suggest:正是一年前, "exactly" in  **ichacha**  :1.确切地，精确地，恰好,....   **jukuu**  :ad. 就 正是 确切 正好 究竟 恰好 正 恰恰   **bkrs**  :正是 (emphasizes that sth is precisely or exactly as stated)
precisely
exactly
even
if
just like
in the same way as正是由于这个原因，我们才放弃的。 We gave up exactly for this reason,

Comment: re；整整 ambiguous， often implies "whole, all", bkrs:1) whole; full
我整整三天没吃饭。 I didn't eat for three days.
2) exactly, also see examples at jukuu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario, I would say "今天正好是你订婚一周年"

正好 
Exactly, and you can also say 正正好好 'absolutely exactly'(don't know how to say it)

---

This is a common word which can be proved by

李同志依了好婆的话去做,果然,**正正好好**的到了头。(文匯月刊, 第 111-115 卷 第25页)

太晚了人家也要怪的,五分钟**正正好好**, (新华文摘 第 7-12 期 第86页)

**正正好好**戴在唐僧的脑袋上 (另眼看四大名著: 西遊記、水滸傳、三國演義、紅樓夢
作者：馬亞麗)

Comment: 正正好好 is not a thing, do you mean 正正好?

Comment: @Tang Ho, I added references,  is it not used in your region??

Comment: This is the answer I've chosen to accept. My (probably fake) friend is Taiwanese, so I think that this is the closest to what I would end up saying to him. I would probably say "剛好" instead of "正好", (and possibly "滿一年" instead of "一周年") but it was close enough to get me on the right track of what I would say.

Comment: @Jacob - never heard anyone saying 正正好好 , too wordy compare to 正好, 整整 and 刚好. Even 正正好 and 刚刚好 sound more natural.

Comment: @TangHo, I think it could be regional. 正正好好 is common in mainland. If you see the difference between 'exact' and 'very exact', then you would see the difference between '正好 ' and '正正好好'. The same kind of concept is that 整齐 -> 整整齐齐，高兴->高高兴兴, 漂亮->漂漂亮亮，.... lots of more.

Comment: @phroureo, You should also aware of the difference between 订婚 and 结婚. Make sure you get that right before you sent it out.

Comment: Thanks Dan. As far as Taiwanese Mandarin goes, 訂婚 is "engaged to be married" and 結婚 is "married."

Answer (score 2):

> “（It's like） you got married to her exactly a year ago！”

There are several variations:

1. （好像）你和她结婚刚好一年整。
2. （好像）你和她结婚正好一年（时间）。
3. （好像）你和她结婚整整一年了。（This variation implies it's been long time(one year) since he got married）

Answer (score 1):

Try '整整‘

We've been married exactly one year.
我们整整结婚一年了。